# Removing an anchor tag `<a href=""></a>` from an array of markup elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, href

Let’s say I have an array with url’s (displayed with `href` attributes) (don’t ask me why, it’s just like that):

```
var MyArray = [
    '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>',
    '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>',
    '<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"></a>'
];
```

I want to make a new Array, with the same url’s but without the anchor tag `<a href=""></a>`, so something like this:

```
var MyNewArray = [
  "http://www.facebook.com/”,
  "http://www.twitter.com/",
  "http://www.cnn.com/"
];
```

Some HTML magic is necessary here…
Thank you guys!

Comment: What language? Javascript? C#?

Comment: More of a Javascript magic

Comment: We prefer Javascript magic

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I would concatenate the strings to construct a jQuery object, then select/map/manipulate the href attribute values from each of the <a> tags from that.  But you don't mention jQuery so you may prefer plain 'ol JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: Just remove the anchor tags from the array and then do a for loop with `MyArray` as the anchors href. so `<a href=MyArray> </a>`

Comment: Did you try `replace` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to append the elements to a temporary DOM container element and then use the native DOM API methods/properties in order to retrieve the desired attribute(s).

In the example below, you can pass the array of elements to a function which will create a temporary `div` container element. The container's [`innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is then set to the joined list of anchor elements. From there you can access the native `href` property and return a mapped array of all the values.

The benefit to this approach is that it will work even if the anchor element string has multiple different attributes in varying order. It would also work if **single quotes** are used around the `href` value rather than **double quotes**.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/qvm6uxgz/)

```
function getAnchorHrefAttributes(elementsArray) {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = elementsArray.join(' ');

  return Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('a')).map((a) => a.href);
}
```

```js
var anchors = ['<a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="test">1</a>',
  '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>',
  '<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"></a>'
];

function getAnchorHrefAttributes(elementsArray) {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = elementsArray.join(' ');

  return Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('a')).map((a) => a.href);
}


var hrefs = getAnchorHrefAttributes(anchors, 'href');
console.log(hrefs);
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use a basic regular expression such as `/href="([^"]+)"/` in order to capture the `href` attribute value. However, I would highly suggest **avoiding** regular expressions for this in favor of the solution above for the aforementioned reasons.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2tsp0phj/)

```
function getAnchorHrefAttributes(elementsArray) {
  return elementsArray.map((a) => {
    var match = a.match(/href="([^"]+)"/);
    return match ? match[1]: null;
  });
}
```

```js
var anchors = ['<a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="test">1</a>',
  '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>',
  '<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"></a>'
];

function getAnchorHrefAttributes(elementsArray) {
  return elementsArray.map((a) => {
    var match = a.match(/href="([^"]+)"/);
    return match ? match[1] : null;
  });
}


var hrefs = getAnchorHrefAttributes(anchors, 'href');
console.log(hrefs);
```

Comment: This solution is the best one.  Fady's would be good if you just want something quick and simple, but this looks like it would be 100% reliable and usable for other things.

Comment: @Nol - Yep, exactly. The first solution would work even if the element has multiple different attributes in varying order. It would also work if single quotes are used rather than double quotes (editing that into the answer).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a loop that loops through every element in your array and use the replace function to replace the tag with an empty string

```
var myString = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>';

   myString = myString.replace('<a href="' , '');
    myString = myString.replace('"></a>' , '');


console.log(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your new array.

```
var MyNewArray = [];
```

Then use a simple for loop to split the array elements every " and insert the required URL into your new array.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < MyArray.length ; i++) MyNewArray[i] = MyArray[i].split('"')[1];
```

That's it.

How does this work?

Your array element `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>` will be splitted into three parts.

```
MyArray[i].split('"')[0] = '<a href='
MyArray[i].split('"')[1] = 'http://www.facebook.com/'
MyArray[i].split('"')[2] = '></a>'
```

So, in every iteration, the second part, i.e. `MyArray[i].split('"')[1]` is your required URL.

Comment: The split on double-quotes puts the HTML of MyArray[i] into the 0th element of an anonymous array and puts the URL into the 1st element - which gets assigned back into MyArray[i].  The for-loop iterates over all the elements in MyArray.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Using the DOM

- Create a placeholder element.
- Combine the array into a string.
- Use `Element#insertAdjacentHTML` to insert the HTML into the placeholder.
- Use `Array#map` to build an array of URLs from the `href` attribute of each link.

```js
var a = ['<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>','<a href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>','<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"></a>'];

const getURLarray = (a, c = document.createElement('div')) => 
    (c.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", a.join('')), [...c.children].map(e => e.href));

console.log(getURLarray(a));
```

#### 2. Splitting the strings

- Use `Array#map` to build an array from the original array
- On each iteration, return the second element from the result of splitting the string by the double quotation mark.

```js
var a = ['<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>','<a href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>','<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"></a>'];

const URLs = a.map(e => e.split('"')[1]);

console.log(URLs);
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop each array then replace `<a href="` and `"></a>` with empty string.

```
var MyArray = ['<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>',
    '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a>',
    '<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"></a>'
    ];

for (var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; ++i) {
   MyArray[i] = MyArray[i].replace("<a href=\"", '');
   MyArray[i] = MyArray[i].replace("\"></a>", '');
}
console.log(MyArray);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?